# Disputed flagged, no idea why

Tags: discussion, flagging

I flagged [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/970793/55235) answer as *not an answer*, it was disputed.

Why I believe it is not answer:

1. The OP is asking for a formal proof, the answer does not provide one. Not only does it not provide one, it gives a, as far as I can see, an **invalid** informal argument, after all the negation of the thesis $(\neg B)\to A$ is not $(\neg B)\to \neg A$
2. The answer gives an informal argument. Informal arguments often are ridiculously trivial when compared to formal proofs and this is one such case. The answer doesn't even come close of being a sufficient hint.

I'd like to know why my flag is disputed and request for the decision to be reversed.

Comment: Regarding point 2, I've considered posting a meta-question about this very common occurrence. Often times people are giving informal arguments as answers asking for formal proofs, which personally I consider no help at all. Informal arguments can suffice if accompanied by a bridge to the formal proof, which almost never happens. I've never went through with posting this because I think it would be useless.

Comment: As far as I know, flagging things as "not an answer" means that you consider that the post doesn't even attempt to answer the question and is talking about something else entirely, or is a request for clarification, etc. It doesn't seem to be the case here. [See this guide (found via the help center).](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81389/when-should-you-decide-whether-to-flag-a-posted-answer-as-not-an-answer/81392#81392)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I've known about this in the past, but after getting acquainted with this criteria, I've seen genuine tries to answer questions get deleted because they in fact don't answer the question. All I want is consistency so I know what and what not to do.

Comment: My opinion (I don't claim to speak for everyone here) is that a downvote is the correct response here: "this answer is not useful". If an answer was deleted this way because it was wrong but didn't fit the criteria, it's (again IMO) a misuse of the system. Maybe other people can weigh in.

Comment: In such a case, why not click on the down arrow?

Comment: @JonasMeyer I don't down vote much and someone already commented saying the answer is not really an answer. And since it's a new user, the chances that he doesn't come back to the site (or the answer) aren't that big, so a deletion would have a better effect than both a common and a downvote.

Comment: @GitGud: One of the advantages of downvoting is making answers easier to delete.  Another is signaling to other users not to waste their time, as opposed to the ambiguous 0 default score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Many (perhaps most) not-an-answer flags are processed by Low Quality review queue, not by moderators. [So was your flag](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/282459). Two reviewers looked at the answer, both clicked *Looks OK*.

So would I, because the answer falls into item 3 of [my flowchart for LQ review](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15233/147263).

Nobody actually flagged your flag as *disputed* -- that thing used to happen in 10K flag queue, which does not exist any more.

Comment: Very informative once again. Your flowchart is your personal decision tool, I'm looking for the official stance. I want to know whether I'm right or wrong in my decision and I want to know exactly what is right and wrong so I can make correct decisions in the future.

Comment: @GitGud But the outcome of reviews is a function of those personal decisions. Review queues are the hive mind of Math.SE, with no single person in charge of their outcomes... *I want to know exactly what is right and wrong* --- would you like world peace with that?

Comment: I understand that. I understand that even if I'm right according to the rules, I can still get disputed due to the reviews. I just want to know what is the correct decision (according to the rules).

Comment: A [moderator](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/15229/147263) answered in the same thread, if it helps. Though the question there is "What is VLQ?", not "What is NAA?" You could start a general thread on the latter topic, so that it can serve as a reference.

Comment: @GitGud I don't think you can get a more official stance than the meta.SE thread I linked.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think you're right.

Comment: @LiveForever, does  anyone really can flag a flag as disputed! How?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey As I wrote, this feature does not exist anymore; only some automatic processes can mark a flag as disputed, not users themselves.

Comment: @LiveForever, one thing I could not understand till now, what is really the *difference between declined and disputed flags*? Why are they different filters?

Comment: @SubhadeepDey See [What is the difference between disputed and declined flags?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292)